# Load a file into F#'s FSI - without using #load

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, f#-scripting, f#-fake

I want to load a file from a .fsx script into into the F# Interactive Session but I can't use #load since I only want to load it if a certain condition is true.

Is there a function like FSI.LoadFile or something instead of the compiler directive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the source code (`fsi.fs`, line 1710 [here](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/fsi/fsi.fs#L1710)

```
        | IHash (ParsedHashDirective("load",sourceFiles,m),_) ->
            fsiDynamicCompiler.EvalSourceFiles (istate, m, sourceFiles, lexResourceManager),Completed
```

Now, some of these parameters are probably easy to fake - in particular `sourceFiles` and `m`.  I suspect that the other parameters are harder to fake.

I suspect that you are not trying to solve the problem in a good way.  An alternative solution may be to do something like

```
let conditionally_load fname cond = 
    if cond then System.IO.File.Copy(fname,"dummy.fs")
    else System.IO.File.Create("dummy.fs")
conditionally_load "something.fs" true
#load "dummy.fs"
```

Although you might need a `;;` before the `#load` to ensure that the function runs before the `#load`

Comment: I have a small follow up question: do you see a reason why #load executes the script every time when I use #load on the same script? I only want to execute it the first time FSI sees it.

Comment: @forki23 - In case the file has changed maybe? - I think this is actually a sensible behaviour - it is very similar to `#include` in C

Comment: there is a big pb though with this approach : it freshens names for loaded classes, which happens everytime the directive is encoutered, which makes two files using the same classes incompatible. this is very bad IMO

Comment: @nicolas - I definitely agree that this is a bad idea - but I can't think of anything more elegant

Comment: wouldn't a 'transactional' behaviour work, like the following : when we load a file, we pass a context, which will stay open for all top level definition. equivalently (?) replace the simple load instruction with a delayed, but topologically sorted, load.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking to do is tricky, since you want the decision on whether to load additional code to be taken at evaluation time. A solution to this would be to modify the shell so that script loading can be scheduled at the next iteration of the REPL. In essence, your `FSI.LoadFile` function would simply add the path to a global queue, in the form of a `ParsedHashDirective("load",["foo.fsx"], ...)` expression.

The queue could then be prepended to the `actions` list next time the `ExecInteractions` method is called in line [1840](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/fsi/fsi.fs#L1840). This should work fine, but clearly you won't be getting any intellisense support.